# Ice4j: What to do once an Agent has finished processing?

Tags: java, networking, ice4j

I am trying to use ice4j in a simple application, but I don't know what to do once an ice Agent finishes processing. Can an application actually write to an IceMediaStream? If not, how can I gather the information to create a stream that I can write to? There is very little documentation for ice4j, and reading through the JUnit tests didn't help either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can recommend to check out the source code for a project called [Jitsi](https://jitsi.org/index.php/Development/VersionControl). Ice4j is a library that was developed mainly as a utility for that project and is used by default in its Jingle(XMPP)-based voice and video communication establishment. Try digging around the net.java.sip.communicator.impl.protocol.jabber.IceUdpTransportManager class.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't gotten any answers for a long time. I tried digging around in the ice4j source code but I couldn't find anything. ice4j provides no documentation for how to use it... :( I'll try looking at the jitsi source.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps try the following tutorial:

[stellarbuild.com/blog/article/ice4j-networking-tutorial-part-1](http://stellarbuild.com/blog/article/ice4j-networking-tutorial-part-1)

You will be able to simply use ice4j as a socket to send information between computers behind different routers.